# Javaで画像ファイルから画像の1部を読み取る

Tags: java, 画像

今Javaで弾幕シューティングゲームを作成しているのですが､弾の画像を使いたいと考え､ネット上でフリーの弾画像を探しまして､[こちら](http://www.danmakufu.net/?%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C%2F%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF#q3fe6871)のサイトの弾幕項目の1番上のものを使おうと考えたのですが､この画像の1つの弾画像をJavaで使うことは可能なのでしょうか｡[image: 弾画像]

Comment: 可能ですが、フレームワークが Android か、 AWT か、 SWT か、 Java2D か、 OpenGL かでコードが変わってくるはずですので、そこを限定してもらえるといいかも。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

一枚画像の位置指定で表示させるのはわりとメジャーな方式です。
下記URLを参考にしてください。

http://www.javadrive.jp/applet/image/index4.html

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡  おかげ様でなんとかできそうです｡